# Implement custom SPI in Keycloak

Tags: java, angular, keycloak

I have started working on KeyCloak with angular and I want to try out adding my own custom SPI. But I am failing to understand the initial process. Like do I need to make a new Java Project or Open some existing project I am unable to find. It is also not clear in the documentation. I would be grateful if someone could help me with the start up, import and set up. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to register a public client check here for more details https://www.keycloak.org/docs/4.8/securing_apps/

Comment: @silentsudo thanks but still it's quite complicated

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you need the following steps:

- be aware of what SPI you want to customize. There are several options like a SPI for User Storage, Theming, Authentication etc. see https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#available-spis for more details.
- for every SPI you need to build a Java Project. Here is an example for a custom UserStorage SPI via HTTP Client https://github.com/adviqo-GmbH/keycloak/compare/master...adviqo-GmbH:feature/http-storage  - this is a diff. You need a pom.xml, some java-classes and at least a property under `META-INF/services/org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageProviderFactory` that contains the reference to a specific class
- then you need to build the SPI module with maven/java.
- the result (here in form of a JAR, but WAR and EAR is possible too) must be placed in `<keycloak-home>/standalone/deployments`.
- Keycloak will identify the new custom SPI during startup.

Thats it. Of course - it's not easy and the documentation https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_providers is not very helpful for beginners.

Comment: This is such a good explanation.  I am trying to do this, but using keycloak running on quarkus.  The deploy of the provider is a little bit different, has anyone had luck making this work? When I log into my keycloak console I can't seem to see the custom SPI in the provider list.

Comment: I don't used Quarkus before, so I cannot give you support here, but maybe a hint. You need a mount point to standalone/deployments and put the JAR into it. Thats what I would do in a default Kubernetes environment. And the JAR must already be there, when you start the Keycloak instance. The classpath is only checked at boot time.

Comment: In the new distribution powered by Quarkus you should copy your providers to the providers directory instead of standalone/deployments